# ManicTime Alternative for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, time-management

Is there software like ManicTime for Windows that can track of everything I do in Mac OS X?

For those who doesn't know what ManicTime is, it is a time tracking software that records your activities on the computer.

Comment: With questiosn like this it generally help to say what the tool you're trying to replicate does. There are doubtless mac users out there who haven't a clue what ManicTime is. Me, for one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a method or application that will enable me to track how long I actively interact with particular applications and/or files on OSX?](http://superuser.com/questions/233503/is-there-a-method-or-application-that-will-enable-me-to-track-how-long-i-activel)

Comment: VTC this one due to the ties to a specific Windows program. The other topic has a much better title.

Comment: Just found that you can vote here to get ManicTime on MAC http://support.manictime.com/forums/222041-feature-requests/suggestions/9360783-manictime-for-mac-os

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found the one I like, so I made [Qbserve](https://qotoqot.com/qbserve/).

It tracks:

- sites opened in Chrome, Safari, Opera browsers
- applications
- window (document) names
- Skype chats and Slack teams

It also knows productivity rates for thousands of sites and apps, so most of the popular ones will be detected automatically. Plus all the tracked information is stored privately on your machine.

**UPD:** now the app also tracks project time automatically and generates invoices.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use Timing https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/timing/id431511738?l=en&mt=12
It tracks windows quite well, can handle documents and can group windows.

Comment: This app currently doesn't seem to provide a visual representation of application open/close times.

Comment: @Pup I have switched to RescueTime.

Answer (score 1):

Check if [Slife](http://www.slifelabs.com/) fits your [requirements](http://www.slifelabs.com/tour).

[image]

> Based on the feedback we have received,
>   we are [open sourcing only the MacOS X client for the time being](http://www.slifelabs.com/development).

Answer (score 1):

[RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com/) is a much better alternative, it saves your data online and the reports are awsome. They have a client for windows and mac

Comment: One thing you won't get with the free version of RescueTime that ManicTime provides: document-level usage stats. For example, using a web browser isn't necessarily bad, depending on whether you're visiting an issue tracking service or just wasting time.

Comment: I don't think u get these feature in the Premium version - check the website.

Comment: It has document tracking feature in the free version now. I've switched to Rescue Time from Timing recently because it has way more useful statistics out of the box. For example it can categorize websites automatically using it's own server side database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the appropriately named [Time Sink](http://manytricks.com/timesink/), $5 shareware by Manytricks.

[image]

Comment: As of this comment, I tried all the offline-only apps listed on this page and found this to be most like ManicTime. The "Activity Report" feature is what I was looking for (app open/close times logged).

Answer (score -1):

TimeLog. It tracks your active window and you can export that. I use ManicTime on Windows and TimeLog on my Mac. TimeLog's not free. If your time is actually worth something though, buy it.

Comment: no document-level report - check the website.

Comment: "Timings" is TimeLog's successor. Here is the official Timings 2 app page: https://www.mediaatelier.com/Timings2/

Comment: This app and its successor, "Timings", currently don't seem to provide a visual representation of application open/close times.