# Monitoring application usage on OS X

Tags: macos, monitoring, productivity, statistics

Is there an application that can track what the active application is, log the information and display the data?

I'm trying to be more productive, so I've been looking at what applications are taking up my time.

Bonus points for being able to:

- Track which website is currently being focused in my browser, e.g. Chrome.
- Track what open files I have in various other applications, such as Photoshop, Xcode, MacVim, etc.
- Automatically dump the data so I can write scripts to process it.

The app would also have to realise when it's gone into screen saver mode.

I would really like to produce my own charts from this data over time, and I'm persistant enough I can keep logging indefinitely and see how my computer usage changes over time.

There is a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/72221/monitoring-my-own-activity-on-computer) specifically for Windows which has been answered with ["Manic Time"](http://www.manictime.com/tour/), which looks just like what I want, but for OS X.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ManicTime Alternative for Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/43311/manictime-alternative-for-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, for some reason, as soon as you ask a question, it becomes indefinitely easier to find the answer by yourself:

This is some sort of social based monitoring software. A tracker runs on your computer and submits your usage to their website. Appears to run under OS X, Linux and Windows.

http://social.wakoopa.com/

Comment: Sadly Wakoopa has shut down.

Answer (score 2):

I really like [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com), it works well and uploads the data to the web, along with sending a weekly email summary thing